# Creating a submodule that relies on a properties file

Tags: python, import, python-import, python-3.7

I have the following structure

```
main.py
module/
    properties.yaml
    file.py
```

file.py relevant code:

```
def read_properties():
    with open('properties.yaml') as file:
        properties = yaml.load(file)
```

main.py relevant code:

```
from module import file
file.read_properties()
```

When `read_properties()` is called within main.py, I get the following error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'properties.yaml'`

What is the recommended way of allowing my module to access the properties file even when imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on answers from @JacobIRR and @BigGerman

I ended up using pathlib instead of os, but the logic is the same. 
Here is the syntax with pathlib for those interested:

in file.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
properties_file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent/"properties.yaml"
with open(properties_file) as file:
    properties = yaml.load(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide the absolute path to `properties.yaml`:

```
with open('/Users/You/Some/Path/properties.yaml') as file:
```

Answer (score 1):

As JacobIRR said in his answer, it is best to use the absolute path to the file. I use the os module to construct the absolute path based on the current working directory. So for your code it would be something like:

```
import os
working_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
properties_file = os.path.join(working_directory, 'module', 'properties.yaml')
```